# Name for the category of modifiers that follow an operand?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, intel

Is there a name for the following category of words "byte, word, long, quad, etc..."?

Also, what is the name for the category of modifiers which indicate the aforementioned in at&t assembly syntax?

For instance, the '`w`' in `movw`, the '`l`' in `movl`, the '`q`' in `movq`, etc...  Is there a name for those?

Thank you.  Sorry if this is a duplicate, I don't know which keywords to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Byte, word, quad, etc are called **size modifiers**.

The *w* in *movw* is called a **size suffix**.

Comment: Just did a quick search using these as terms, looks like this is the answer!